# Coffeescript + Atom : Binding listeners

Tags: coffeescript, bind, atom-editor

My problem is that if i create listeners on a loop, then the listener callback functions use the last value of the loop index when they are called. I guess this is a problem of binding the callback function, but i can't figure out how. See the following example:

```
{TextEditor, Disposable, Range, Point, Atom} = require 'atom'

class TestGuy
  constructor:(n,id) ->
    @marker = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().markBufferRange([[n,0],[n+1,0]])
    @id = id


class TestGuys
  constructor:() ->
    @markID = 0
    @disposables = []

  bundle:() ->
    for i in [0...2]
      testguy = new TestGuy([i,@markID)
      console.log(testguy.id) #prints 0,1 as i expect
      @markID += 1
      @disposables.push testguy.marker.onDidChange (event) =>
        console.log(testguy.id) #when i invalidate markers, these callbacks print 1,1, but i expected 0,1 !

atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor', 'custom:test', ->
  testobject = new TestGuys()
  testobject.bundle()
```

So when callbacks are called, both of them use i = 1 even though the first callback function was defined for i=0